# Get the values from an xml and send it as two separate files using java

Tags: java, xml

I have an xml like the below one.

```
<Input>
   <test>
      ....
   </test>
   <test>
      ....
   </test>
</Input>
```

Now, I have to get the two  messages including the tag  and send it as two separate messages. I can check start by checking if the message starts with  and then proceed. How can I proceed after that? Can any one please help?

Answer (score 0):

using dom4j to parse the xml document

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

code example:

```
    Document xmlDoc = DocumentHelper.parseText(text);
    Element root = xmlDoc.getRootElement();

    List elements = root.elements();
    for(Element test: elements) {
        System.out.println(test.getText());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know if it is going to help, but I would try to solve the problem using NodeList, something like:

```
try {
String configPath = "path/to/file.xml";
            File configFile = new File(configPath);
            if (configFile.exists()) {
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = dBuilder.parse(new FileInputStream(configFile));

                NodeList nodes = doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("test");
                for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++){
                          Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);
                          // Do something with the element found
                }
            } else{
                throw new IOException("Not found config file: " + configPath);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
             // Do something with the Exception catched
    }
```

I hope it helped :)